# JavaScript AngularJS call function in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a checkbox.

If **checked** -> call one function displayBus(number)

If **unchecked** -> call other function displayCar()

The problem with this code is that I have to click also in hide or show to call the function.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" />
        <div ng-show="mycheckbox">
             <a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="displayBus(number);">hide</a>

        </div>
        <div  ng-hide="mycheckbox">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="displayCar();">show</a>
        </div>
```

But I just want to check / Uncheck and then call automaticly the function.
I DO NOT want to click on hide or show.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wire up an ng-change to the checkbox and then check it's value:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="dataChanged()" />
```

and then in your javascript:

```
$scope.dataChanged = function(){
    if($scope.mycheckbox){
        //checked
    }
    else{
        //not checked
    }
};
```

---

**Edit**:

If you want to do it only in html:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="myCheckbox ? displayBus(number) : displayCar()">hide</a>
```

---

**Edit**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="myCheckbox ? displayBus(number) : displayCar()" />
```

Comment: Thanks but better if it is not in JavaScript but HTML

Comment: I need to have check/uncheck. Then it will execute displayBus(number) or displayCar()

Comment: Please describe your question a little better as I am confused on what you're trying to accomplish.